# Mongoose updateOne wraps the target document in an additional array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to update a document in a nested array.

Performing an updateOne from the mongo cli:

```
db.tasks.updateOne({
  task: "goose", 
  tags: {
    $elemMatch:
      { _id: ObjectId("65400b04b5a313bcbe745c3c") }
  }
}, {
  $set: {
    "tags.$": {
      "name": "bar",
      "color": "green",
    }
  }
})
```

gives me the result I expect:

```
{ task: "goose", tags: [ {name: "foo", ...}, {name: "bar", color: "green", ...}, ... ] }
```

The mongoose query looks practically the same to me except this time its managed by the mongoose model.

```
TaskModel.updateOne(
  {
    task: "goose",
    tags: {
      $elemMatch:
        { _id: ObjectId("65400b04b5a313bcbe745c3c") }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "tags.$": {
        name: "bar",
        color: "green",
        "_id": ObjectId("65400b04b5a313bcbe745c3c")
      }
    }
  }
)
```

The result is:

```
{ task: "goose", tags: [ {name: "foo", ...}, [ {name: "bar", color: green, ...} ], ... ] }
```

I was expecting mongoose to have the same behavior as seen in the mongo cli version but notice that the document containing the "bar" tag becomes wrapped in an additional array.

I've essentially solved the problem by dropping down to the mongo driver using `TaskModel.collection.updateOne` instead but I'm wondering if I'm misconfiguring the mongoose query in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Your `TaskModel.updateOne` looks fine and without seeing your `Task` schema the `$set` should set the `tags` element at position `1` to the new object. If `tags` is defined as an array of objects then I'm surprised mongoose didn't throw an error as you can't add an array to a non-array type object.

It would be good if you posted your schema.

In the meantime, if you know you are only going to be setting a couple of fields to new values you can always do this:

```js
   $set: {
      "tags.$.name": 'bar',
      "tags.$.color": 'green'
   }
```

That will only overwrite the specified fields and not the entire object.

Comment: Upgrading mongoose from v7.6.3 to the new 8.0.0 release seems to resolve the issue for me.

Comment: Wow that's quick. I didn't know 8.0 was out yet. Thanks for telling me and glad you got it working.

Comment: Looks like I spoke too soon.
I'm seeing the same behavior with 8.0
I used an alternative example in my OP. Here's a trimmed down version of the actual schema:


    let itemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      incidentDate: String,
      incidentSeverity: String,
      incidentType: String,
      incidentDescription: String,
      incidentYear: Number
    })
    
    let schema = new mongoose.Schema({
      key: String,
      incidents: [itemSchema]
    })

Comment: I still don't see any problems with your schema. Your `itemSchema` looks simple enough and that schema is being assigned as the value to the `incidents` array correctly.  Mongoose shouldn't be adding an array item into `incidents` because `incidents` only accepts a document that matches the `itemSchema`.

Comment: I'm going to assume this is a mongoose regression. The exact issue was reported and fixed in 2017. https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5628. Falling back to the underlying mongo driver using Model.collection.updateOne works for me. Thanks for looking into this.